# Unable to open Operator

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, operator-keyword, status

I am trying to run Pig Latin script on Hadoop, and I am getting the error Unable to open terator for alias result.

Now this is not a script issue, I have tested it on a small test file, and it has worked.

I have the feelling it is the Reduce Function, becuase the script runs longer than 2 hours, then it fails noting : `Successfully read Input, failed to produce result!`

I am getting this warning too :

```
2015-01-09 09:29:13,320 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: server:port. Already tried 0 
enter code here
time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2015-01-09 09:29:14,321 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: server:port. Already tried 1 
time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2015-01-09 09:29:15,322 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client - Retrying connect to server: server:port. Already tried 2 
time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=3, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2015-01-09 09:29:15,429 [main] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ClientServiceDelegate -
Application state is completed. FinalApplicationStatus=SUCCEEDED. Redirecting to job history server
2015-01-09 09:29:15,847 [main] INFO
org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Some
jobs have failed! St
op running all dependent jobs
2015-01-09 09:29:15,854 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1066:Unable to open iterator for alias result
```

What does that mean ?? what does FinalAPplicationStatus=SUCCEEDED mean?
Thanks very much

Comment: Any  Idea   ??? There must be some reason for this

Comment: I note that it tries to connect the maximum number of tries, perhaps that part fails? Does it also take 2 hours to fail when you only feed it a tiny bit of input data? -- For people who found this post when looking for [ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34495085/error-1066-unable-to-open-iterator-for-alias-in-pig-generic-solution) here is a [generic solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34495086/983722).